# Beamer : shift a relative overlay sequence

Tags: beamer, overlays

I made a command with relative averlay sequence that appears several times in the presentation starting at different moments.

I tried this, but the second sequence start at slide 2 and appears only frame slide 3.

How to make it beginning on slide 3 ?

I prefer to avoid to pass an argument for the shift because the overlays are complexe in the command.

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\newcommand{\SBS}{%
    \only<+->{Step}
    \only<.(1)->{by}
    \only<.(2)->{step}
}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}

\SBS

\only<3->{\SBS}

\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the specification `\only<+(1)->{\SBS}`:

[image]

The code:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\makeatletter
\def\c@slideinframe{\beamer@slideinframe}
\def\beamerslideinframe{\beamer@slideinframe}
\makeatother

\newcommand{\SBS}{%
    \only<+->{Step}
    \only<.(1)->{by}
    \only<.(2)->{step}
}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Slide~\arabic{slideinframe}}
\SBS

\only<+(1)->{\SBS}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```